# Carthage update error: "GitHub API request failed: Bad credentials"

Tags: swift, realm, carthage

Here is my Cartfile:

```
# Kanna HTML parsing library
github "tid-kijyun/Kanna" ~> 1.0.0

# Realm database/ORM
github "realm/realm-cocoa"
```

When I run `carthage update` I get this:

```
$ carthage --version
Unrecognized command: '--version'. See `carthage help`.

$ carthage update --platform OSX
*** Fetching realm-cocoa
*** Fetching Kanna
*** Skipped downloading realm-cocoa.framework binary due to the error:
    "GitHub API request failed: Bad credentials"
*** Checking out realm-cocoa at "v0.98.3"
*** Skipped downloading Kanna.framework binary due to the error:
    "GitHub API request failed: Bad credentials"
*** Checking out Kanna at "1.0.5"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/p2/c_d5mx0s3gl45165btrpx1fm0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.KVYEob.log
*** Building scheme "Kanna_OSX" in Kanna.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "RealmSwift" in RealmExamples.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Realm" in RealmExamples.xcworkspace
```

So it does seem to build both Kanna and Realm, but I'm getting an error about bad GitHub API credentials. What is wrong?

Comment: Which version of Carthage are you using? You can determine this by running `carthage version`.

Comment: @jpsim `carthage version` says `0.15`.

Comment: I'm no Carthage expert, but from the error message, it would appear your GitHub API credentials are invalid. From reading Carthage's source (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/0.15/Source/CarthageKit/GitHub.swift#L378-L409), it would appear it's using `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` to authenticate GitHub API requests. Do you have this value set as an environment variable? If so, is it a valid token? Have you recently revoked this token on GitHub.com? If your token is valid & not revoked, I recommend you file an issue towards the Carthage project as this may be a bug.

Comment: @jpsim Thanks for researching. I don't have a `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN` env var set. Unless I'm missing it, I don't see anything in Carthage's `README.md` about setting up GitHub API credentials or env vars. Are you saying that GitHub API credentials are required to use Carthage??

Comment: No, GitHub API credentials are not required to use Carthage! But if set, Carthage will attempt to use it for getting binaries for your frameworks from GitHub releases. Please file an issue on https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/new and someone more familiar with Carthage will be able to help you.

Comment: @jpsim Done. https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution in response to a [Carthage issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1188#issuecomment-195918921) I raised:

1. Edit `~/.gitconfig` and add the following:

   `[credential]
     helper = osxkeychain
   [credential "https://github.com"]
     username = willhains`

   (Replace `willhains` with your GitHub user ID.)
2. Clone a private repo via HTTPS.
3. OSX will prompt for your GitHub password.
4. Run `carthage update`.

Comment: Not able to open ~/.gitconfig , Permission Denied.

Comment: @coreDeviOS Use the `sudo` command when opening that file.
Keep in mind that you need to open the file with some text editor. For example, you can use built-in nano editor:
`sudo nano ~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip looking for binaries and just build from source:

```
carthage update --no-use-binaries
```