# Carthage error "Bad credentials"

Tags: xcode7, carthage

Instructions: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk

Errors:

```
*** Skipped downloading ios-sdk.framework binary due to the error:
"Bad credentials"

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carthage update error: "GitHub API request failed: Bad credentials"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790585/carthage-update-error-github-api-request-failed-bad-credentials)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the solution in response to a Carthage issue willhains raised:

1. Edit `~/.gitconfig` and add the following:

   ```
   [credential]
       helper = osxkeychain
   [credential "https://github.com"]
       username = willhains
   ```

   *Replace willhains with your GitHub user ID.*
2. Clone a private repo via HTTPS.
3. OSX will prompt for your GitHub password.
4. Run Carthage update.

OR
You can delete the GitHub credential form you Keychain access and use..
Hope this will help

Comment: I deleted the github credentials from keychain access

Comment: deleting the github credential from using the OSX KeyChain Access app worked for me :-)

Comment: Note that `username`  is actually your `user id` which can be found under https://api.github.com/users/<yourusername> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308954/where-can-i-find-the-github-id-in-my-account)

Answer (score 1):

For in my case:

I changed my Github username and **forgot to change local credentials**(only username) stored in Keychain Access.

Do change the username to your new one and voila!